# Commands not identified when copy/pasted, but are identified when manually written

Tags: c++, c, netbeans

I am having a weird bug in using netbeans and C/C++ plugin along with that.
When I copy/paste a code, it gives me error `Unable to resolve identifier` on every function (*including main*). But if i manually type same code/program, its all good and working and compiles/runs perfectly. Can anyone explain that to me? Normal java projects work just fine (the copy/pasting code doesnt give any sort of error), its just the problem with C/C++ projects (havent tried others yet). I not only want to know solution, but also the possible cause (out of curosity).

EDIT:
Here's an example of an infinite loop i was trying (say for fun? lol)->

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char a;
for(a=32;a<128;a=a+1)
printf(“%3d = ‘%c’\t”,a,a);
return(0);
}
```

This program goes on displaying keyboard characters and their ASCII codes over and over endlessly. If I manually type this program, its all good. If I copy paste this code, it gives me error as stated above (on every variable and function. For ex- "Unable to resolve identifier" on main function).

Some backstory (not related to problem really)...
Actually I am using netbeans because of its features. The way it tells about a lot of errors right on real-time bases, its auto bracket closing feature, the ui cleanliness (or maybe I am used to it). I just started leaning C a while ago, though I am quite advanced in java (the reason I have netbeans, I dont use eclipse because of drag and drop interface, which basically cuts a lot of time for me. I know there are plugins now that enable that in eclipse too, so I might give it a try but for now I am used to netbeans' interface). My teacher recommended me bloodshed C/C++ (which i didnt like, its like a plain notepad with just the ability to compile) or turbo C (which proves my teacher to be of ancient times). And he told me visual studio was too advanced for me right now. So i decided to stick with netbeans. Except this problem, everything is working perfect as of whatever I have tried right now.

Also, as of side note, do you guys think me sticking with netbeans for C/C++ for now is ok (ok in sense I am wondering about the cons)? I think I'll move on to visual studio later....

Comment: What happen if you change one line of the paste code ? Are you looking for an editor or an ide ?

Comment: I cannot explain to you why Netbeans does that, but i would strongly sugges to a) Get a dedicated C++ IDE such as VS 2013, Code::Blocks, the updated DevC++, QT Creator, .. .  And b) please come clear about what you actually want to develop in. Either C or C++. You do not mix these two languages despite the possibility of compiling C as C++. Do these two steps and you will save yourself a lot of work! :)

Comment: Try using `printf("%3d = '%c'\t",a,a);` instead of `printf(“%3d = ‘%c’\t”,a,a);`

Comment: In example you provide invalid quotes `printf(“%3d = ‘%c’\t”,a,a);`, they should be `printf("%3d = ‘%c’\t",a,a);`. Visual Studio is not more advanced than Netbeans. You can try qt creator as IDE.

Comment: oh ok, thanks lol. Such a minor mistake -.- Solved the prob, thanks again :D And will try other compilers, more dedicated ones :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have in your question won't compile on any compiler. Why?

You are using [curly quotes](http://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html) here:

```
printf(“%3d = ‘%c’\t”,a,a);
```

`“` and `”` are different from `"`. Use `"` instead of `“` and `”` to fix the problem.
`‘` and `’` might also cause problems. Replace them with `'`